Extracting Source Code from Nuget Package File

Extract Code from Nuget Package

Can i extract complete source code from a nuget package File? e.g. (Filename.nupkg)
I was trying to decrypt a nuget package and get its source code.
I have tried decompilers like dotpeek but no luck.
It just gave me an overview of how that code was compiled
Links i have searched are below
Extracting Nupkg files using command line

Most nuget packages does not contain any source code to extract. If they do then I would assume that they also publish it elsewhere (like Github). If not then decompiling is the only way to view the "source", though it won't match the original source exactly.

you may enable "SourceLink" which will search for the packages sourcecode on the internet, assuming it was even published (e.g. on github or Azure DevOps)

@MakePeaceGreatAgain..kindly let me know how can i enable "SourceLink" any article?

If the package contains source code, it's in reality just a .zip file, so you can just extract it and look. If doesn't contain the source code, then that won't work.

Before decompiling anything, I'd first try to find that package on nuget.org, follow the "Source repository" link. If that's not leading you anywhere, then follow the "Project website" link and try to read up on it there if they released sources in any shape or form. If neither happens to be the case: why do you think you need the sources in the first place? If that project doesn't want you to see their sources, maybe switch to another one, that does?

@Fildor, I have to create custom activites for UiPath.
Thats why I need the source,cause Activites build with (.Net 4.7) framework will no longer supported in UiPath Studio
I have to upgrade them so the people can use it with latest version of (.Net) framework Like .Net Core
I have to upgrate the framework for those Packages
